# javascript Module? export default class ? What is it, how do I use it?

Tags: javascript, module

I'm a bit of a javascript newbie.  I came across a program I need to use, but if I understand this correctly, it's in the form of a Javascript "Module", I think.

The program starts with `export default class` I believe I need to convert it to a regular .js file to add to my webpage, correct?

Do I need another program to convert this or make it work?  I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a transpiler to transpile the code for you, [babel](https://babeljs.io/) is a common transpiler which you can use for doing transpilation. I believe the documentation on babel js will be able to provide you with most of the resources you need to get started.